# Passing an ID via a String to display results in a Gridview VS Literal Control

Tags: c#

I have a web application that consist of a page with two urls, when clicked they respectively displays products onto another 
page from the Products table of the Northwind DB according to Supplier ID. All works well when using a Literal Control, 
howerver, in experimenting around, I changed the Literal Control into a Gridview, now instead of Listing all the 
respective products, I get one column that displays the last product only of the respective Supplier ID group. e.g.
Results: Item:  C h a n g
... Could someone please point me in the direction as to what I'm  doing wrong/Missing. Here is my code

```
/******** Hypertext (page with the URLs):
<div>
        <div><a href="gridtest.aspx?orderList=1">Supplier ID 1</a> </div>
        <div><a href="gridtest.aspx?orderList=2">Supplier ID 2</a> </div>

</div>
/******** Hypertext (page with the Gridview):
<asp:GridView ID="gvSupplies" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
/********* code behind gridview page:
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string mySQLQuery = null;
        string vID = Request.QueryString["orderList"];

        mySQLQuery = "SELECT SupplierID, ProductName, UnitPrice, UnitsOnOrder FROM Products WHERE (SupplierID = SupplierID) AND SupplierID ='" + vID + "' ORDER BY ProductName  ";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, connection);
        SqlDataReader myReader1 = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

       while ((myReader1.Read()))
        {
          gvSupplies.DataSource = myReader1.GetString(1) + " " + myReader1.GetValue(2);
          gvSupplies.DataBind();
       }

      connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused on how the gridview(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) works.  I would go grab some tutorials that talk about databinding in Asp.net with views.

For the short term a grid view is meant to represent a table of data.  You should only bind data to it once.  By default it will attempt to pick out the columns and rows and display something based on that.

```
while ((myReader1.Read()))
        {
          gvSupplies.DataSource = myReader1.GetString(1) + " " + myReader1.GetValue(2);
          gvSupplies.DataBind();
       }
```

TO

```
      gvSupplies.DataSource = myReader1;
      gvSupplies.DataBind();
```